# Why am I not getting the right output for this implementation of nth Fibo Number?

Tags: c++, fibonacci

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void mul ( long long f[2][2], long long m[2][2] );

void power (long long f[2][2], long long int n );
int fibo (long long int n);
int main (void)
{
    int c;
    cin>>c;
    while (c!= 0)
    {
        int n,val;

        cin>>n;
        val = fibo(n);
        cout<<val<<"\n";
        c--;
    }
    return 0;
} 

int fibo (long long int n)
{
    long long f[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 0;
    else
        power(f,n-1);
    return f[0][0];            
}


void power (long long f[2][2], long long int n )
{
    if ( n == 0 )
        return;
    long long m[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    if ( n % 2 == 0 )
    {
        mul(f,f);
        power(f,n/2);
    }
    else
    {
        mul(f,f);
        mul(f,m);
        power(f,(n-1)/2);
    }
}

void mul ( long long f[2][2], long long m[2][2] )  
{ 
    long long x = f[0][0]*m[0][0] + f[0][1]*m[1][0];
    long long y = f[0][0]*m[0][1] + f[0][1]*m[1][1];
    long long z = f[1][0]*m[0][0] + f[1][1]*m[1][0];
    long long w = f[1][0]*m[0][1] + f[1][1]*m[1][1];
    f[0][0] = x;
    f[0][1] = y;
    f[1][0] = z;
    f[1][1] = w;
}
```

I made this code using the matrix exponentiation by squaring method. However, I am not getting the right answer. Why is that?
Why am I not getting the correct output for the Fibo number for this? I am getting the output as

```
3rd Term: 8
4th Term: 21
5th Term: 55
6th Term: 377
```

Why is this happeining? I tried using the debugger but I am not able to spot the error.

Comment: In your `power` function you wrote `if (n == 0 ) return;` but missed `if (n == 0 || n == 1) return;`. I'm assuming you're trying to replicate [this code](http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-find-fibonacci-numbers-matrix-exponentiation/) based on your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995099/fibonacci-by-matrix-exponentiation-by-squaring)

Comment: I read that code. However, I am implementing it on my own. I don't want to copy it. I am trying to go by the concept.

Comment: And why should I include 1 there? Because, in the end, even if it is an odd number, it will come down to 0 itself.

Comment: Also, I tried that just now, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Step through your code with `n=1` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The `power(...)` function looks buggy. How about this:

```
void power (long long f[2][2], long long int n )
{
    if ( n == 1 || n == 0 )  // if n == 1, the matrix f^1 should be kept untouched.
        return;              // if n == 0, f should be an identity. it is
                             // a special case here because of your divide-and-
                             // conquer logic.
    long long m[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    if ( n % 2 == 0 )
    {
        power(f,n/2);        // given f = m^(n/2) is ready
        mul(f,f);            // m^n = m^(n/2) x m^(n/2)
    }
    else
    {
        power(f,(n-1)/2);    // given f = m^((n-1)/2) is ready
        mul(f,f);            // m^(n-1) = m^((n-1)/2) x m^((n-1)/2)
        mul(f,m);            // m^n = m^(n-1) x m
    }
}
```

Comment: I have two doubts. At any point of time, will n be ever equal to 0. Why have you put it in an if condition in the if statement above. Secondly, in the `if( n% 2 == 0 )` if I interchange the order of statements, `power(f,n/2)` and `mul(f,f)`, it shouldn't affect the answer. But it does, why is that?

Comment: q1: Your main loop allows user to input n = 1 which will cause a fibo(1), which will cause a power(f, 0) to be calculated.

Comment: Can you help with the second question as well?

Comment: @Qin q2: It can be assumed that f will always hold what we expect after power(...), which is a critical property when implementing recursive functions. I can hardly explain why interchanging these 2 lines is wrong right now. Maybe a walkthrough with an odd number (like n = 3,5,7...) would help you understand that.